# Android Studio gradle sync failed: no cached version

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-developer-api, android-gradle-3.1.0

**While starting android, GRADLE SYNC failed and this error pop up**

Gradle sync failed: No cached version of com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2 available for offline mode.
Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log) (4m 29s 435ms)

Please help to solve this error.

Comment: Your gradle sync might be turned off, go to File-> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deplyment -> Gradle.. Under global gradle setting, uncheck the "offline work" checkbox and Apply -> OK . Then try to sync again the project

Answer (score 2):

Uncheck Offline mode setting in Build and Execution Setting, and then sync the project.

Answer (score 1):

In new Android Studio 3.6.3 Version which I am using Offline Mode setting is in gradle which is right side of the Android Studio[image]